# Does changing private module fragments cause a recompilation of a module?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

On [this page about the C++20 module feature](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-modules-private-module-fragment-and-header-units), I discovered this statement:

> Thanks to a private module fragment, you can implement a module in one file and declare its last part as its implementation using `module :private;`. **Consequently, a modification of the private module fragment does not cause recompilation.**

Emphasis added.

Is that statement accurate? Do changes to a private module fragment cause "recompilation?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a lot more complicated than it seems, as "recompilation" could mean a lot of things and the website doesn't go into detail.

Where the website is potentially correct is this: do changes to a module's private fragment cause code which *imports* that module to be recompiled? The answer here is "maybe".

Because the module interface did not change, the module file representing this interface is identical to what it was under the last compilation. So a smart implementation of modules could do a quick comparison between the newly generated module file and the previous one. If they are the same, then it could choose not to overwrite the old file, thereby avoiding causing recompilation of dependent files.

But that is mere possibility; a better question is whether actual implementations do that. Visual Studio 2022 is probably the build system with the most mature module support.

From what I can tell, the native build functionality of VS2022 does not attempt to detect if a compiled module interface matches the one already on disk. If it detects that it needs to recompile any part of a file that contributes to a module's interface, then it presumes that the interface itself has changed. And therefore, all files importing that module need to be rebuilt.

Note that this does not happen when using a module implementation unit. If you change the contents of an implementation unit, that does not provoke the rebuilding of the module interface, so it does not provoke the recompilation of code which includes that interface.

If the question is whether changes to a module's private fragment causes the module interface to be recompiled, the answer is almost certainly "yes" (and certainly for VC2022).

Sure, it is *theoretically* possible for a build system to detect that only the private module fragment has changed. But it would involve either compiling the interface portion anyway (to compare it against the one on-disk) or storing the textual version of the interface on-disk and comparing that to the file's version. Neither is a particularly good idea.

Comment: _If the question is whether changes to a module's private fragment causes the module interface to be recompiled, the answer is almost certainly "yes"._ I do hope that's not true.  It would make modules a lot less useful.

Comment: @PaulSanders: How could it possibly *work?* Do you think the compiler can just magically skip to the private module fragment? Putting everything in a single text file means that all the stuff in that file is inherently linked. That's *why* we have multiple files that are all part of a module. Private module fragments are a compatibility feature, making it easier to create a simple single-file module as an alternative interface for a library. Such things don't get modified often.

Comment: But but but - isn't the operative word here _linked_?  To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules): `Private module fragment ends the portion of the module interface unit that can affect the behavior of other translation units.`  I read that to mean that they therefore don't need to be recompiled, although I do concede that a build system might have a hard time implementing that.  But build systems are getting pretty smart, especially IDEs.  And maybe such an optimisation isn't actually all that useful in practise, I could believe that too.

Comment: @PaulSanders: "*isn't the operative word here linked?*" No. C++ modules have very little to do with what happens at link time.

Comment: Alright, I guess there might be changes in the private fragment that affect, for example, the layout or size of an object.  That would certainly invalidate what I am saying.

Comment: @PaulSanders: You're not thinking of things from a build system perspective. The first thing the build system sees is that a file has a more recent modification date than the product file it produces. That is what makes it perform recompilation. It's not that things you do in the private fragment will affect the interface; it's that the build system *only sees one file*. Which, again, is why private module fragments are a compatibility feature, not a thing you should use. If you want to prevent cascading recompilation, put your implementation in another file.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, and you're probably right.  Authors of build tools are unlikely to try to make them clever enough to handle this when the programmer has a viable alternative.

Comment: OK, since I made a bit of a fool of myself over this I ran a simple test, using Visual Studio 2022 (whose behaviour I think you already know about).  And you're right.   Changing the private fragment of a module causes any TU's importing that module to be recompiled.  I will now crawl back to my lair and lick my wounds, serves me right.