# Cyclic dependencies with C++20 modules and the private fragment

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, circular-dependency, c++-modules

Can the private module fragment be used to break cyclic dependencies in the same way that implementation source files can? This example is using Visual Studio 2022 Preview.

This is an example that compiles successfully without the private module fragment and how I expect you would solve this issue.

`ModuleA.ixx`

```
export module ModuleA;
import ModuleB;

export class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB foo;
    void sayHello();
};
```

`ModuleA.cpp`

```
module;
#include <iostream>
module ModuleA;

void ClassA::sayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

`ModuleB.ixx`

```
export module ModuleB;

export class ClassB
{
public:
    void sayHello();
};
```

`ModuleB.cpp`

```
module ModuleB;
import ModuleA;

void ClassB::sayHello()
{
    ClassA bar;
    bar.sayHello();
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
import ModuleB;

int main()
{
    ClassB baz;

    baz.sayHello();

    return 0;
}
```

This is an example using the same main.cpp and the private module fragment that results in a cyclic dependency error.

`ModuleA.ixx`

```
export module ModuleA;
import ModuleB;

export class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB foo;
    void sayHello();
};

module :private;
import <iostream>;

void ClassA::sayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

`ModuleB.ixx`

```
export module ModuleB;

export class ClassB
{
public:
    void sayHello();
};

module :private;
import ModuleA;

void ClassB::sayHello()
{
    ClassA bar;
    bar.sayHello();
}
```

So, what is the difference between these two implementations and why does one work but the other doesn't?

Comment: When you import a module, that module interface has to be compiled first. Otherwise there is nothing to import. So which module do you compile first, the chicken or the egg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original example worked because each of the four files were *separate* translation units (TU). The implementation units each required the other modules' interface units, but the interface units themselves had no dependencies on the implementation units. So both interface units could be compiled before either implementation unit. Thus both module interfaces are available to both implementation units.

By combining each module's interface and implementation units into the same file, you put them in the same TU. The fact that part of it is in a private module fragment changes *nothing* about this. They are compiled at the same time since they're all part of the same TU. So the `import ModuleB` directive must be processed while compiling `ModuleA`, which means that `ModuleB` must be compiled, which requires processing the `import ModuleA` directive.

Which is a cycle.

Put simply, private module fragments are not separate files to be processed by the compiler.

Comment: I found this confusing since looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314015/does-changing-private-module-fragments-cause-a-recompilation-of-a-module) it stated that theoretically dependent modules do not have to be recompiled if only the private fragment changed which made me think that the interface and the private module fragment are separate. But since it says they currently are recompiled this makes sense.

Comment: @DobizGazer: That question and answer were presuming changes that would actually compile. The circular dependency would prevent compilation from functioning. Even in the theoretical possibility outlined there where it might sometimes work, doing a full recompile would immediately fail due to the circular dependency.